# "through an analysis" vs "through analysis"

Tags: nouns, syntactic-analysis, indefinite-articles

> **Through analysis of my studio work**; which has explored and utilised precious materials, alternative materials, CAD and traditional bench skills, the journal pinpoints the positive and negative ways these factors have informed my work.

Would you say - **Through analysis** of my studio work or **Through an analysis** of my studio work?

Comment: Tip: go for shorter, simpler sentences.  Break the long ones up into shorter ones.

Answer (score 3):

"Through analysis of my studio work" (verb) denotes ongoing analysis or perhaps more than one study, whereas "through an analysis of my studio work" (noun) infers a specific study was done.  In other words, the former phrase refers to a general (or casual) analysis while the latter refers to a specific (or more rigorous) analysis.

Comment: This is the full sentence, Through analysis of my studio work; which has explored and utilised precious materials, alternative materials, CAD and traditional bench skills, the journal pinpoints the positive and negative ways these factors have informed my work.

Comment: using your explanation I believe that 'an' should be used